# fetch throwing "only absolute urls are supported" in react redux server-side render

Tags: react-redux, fetch

`fetch` started throwing "only absolute urls are supported" whenever my redux app was rendered on the server, but worked perfectly fine client-side.  It also used to work for relative URLs so I don't know what went wrong.

Help?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was no longer importing `fetch` from `domain-task` - somehow I had lost the following line:

```
import { fetch } from 'domain-task';
```

Since `fetch` is also native, the compiler didn't complain, and it worked client-side.  This line fixed it for the server-side render.